# Box2D rotate an object, how?

Tags: java, android, rotation, box2d

How I can rotate an object in `Box2D`?  Tried..

```
private static final double DEGREES_TO_RADIANS = (double)(Math.PI/180);
float angle = (float) (45*DEGREES_TO_RADIANS);
object.body.setTransform(object.body.getPosition(), angle);
```

..but not working.

Comment: I take it you are using jBox2D?

Comment: yeah i use box2d for java/android / rokon

Answer (score 2):

Firstly the object must be a **dynamic** or **kinematic** to be able to be rotated, 
in addition use **`SetAngularVelocity()`** to achieve the rotation.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to rotate the object to an angle then you use setTransform method like

`b2body->SetTransform( playerBody_->GetPosition(), angleInRadian );`

And if you want to rotate the body continuously then use SetAngularVelocity method like

`b2body->SetAngularVelocity(<float32>)`

Remember b2body object must be a dynamic or kinematic to be able to be rotated.

Answer (score 1):

use the world center instead position, like this

```
private static final double DEGREES_TO_RADIANS = (double)(Math.PI/180);
float angle = (float) (45*DEGREES_TO_RADIANS);
object.body.setTransform(object.body.getWorldCenter(), angle);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use force or impulses,not use setTransform methord directly.
example:

```
body->ApplyForce( b2Vec2(force,0), body->GetWorldPoint( b2Vec2(1,1) ) );
```

this code let body rote.

Answer (score -1):

The idea is to rotate to an angle, the easiest method I found by myself is to use:

```
float rotation = MathUtils.PI; // target rotation

float c = 1; //speed of rotation
float q = rotation-groundBody.getAngle();
groundBody.setAngularVelocity(c*q);
```

the body will rotate quicker at the beginning and slower at the end but you can use Interpolation function to achieve desired speed of rotation.